# restart windows service from the same windows service

Tags: c#

I am trying to restart a windows service from the same windows service with this code:

```
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("net.exe", "stop " + serviceName);
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psi.UseShellExecute = true;
            psi.WorkingDirectory = Environment.SystemDirectory;
            var st = Process.Start(psi);
            st.WaitForExit();

            psi = new ProcessStartInfo("net.exe", "start " + serviceName);
            psi.UseShellExecute = true;
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psi.WorkingDirectory = Environment.SystemDirectory;
            st = Process.Start(psi);
            st.WaitForExit();
```

It is not working but is this even possible from the same service?

If it is possible then can anyone suggest why this does not work?

Comment: What do you expect, what actually happens, and what have you done to troubleshoot it so far?

Comment: I expect the service to restart.  I am not sure how to redirect the output of the net commands to a file so I don't know what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's a clean way of doing this. Once you stop the service, the process is no longer there to start it.

One slightly dirty solution:
You could configure the service to restart on error (e.g. at installation/registration time).

Then when you want to restart programmatically have your service exit with an error e.g. by calling:

```
Environment.Exit(-1)
```

or

```
Environment.FailFast("Service stopped because...")
```

Note: If there is a cleaner way of doing this programmatically the account the service is running under would require permissions to be able to restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because once you reach the middle, execution stops in since both parent and child process exit:

```
/* Running */            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("net.exe", "stop " + serviceName);
/* Running */            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
/* Running */            psi.UseShellExecute = true;
/* Running */            psi.WorkingDirectory = Environment.SystemDirectory;
/* st stops svc */       var st = Process.Start(psi);
/* both exit */          st.WaitForExit();

/* never reached */      psi = new ProcessStartInfo("net.exe", "start " + serviceName);
/* never reached */      psi.UseShellExecute = true;
/* never reached */      psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
/* never reached */      psi.WorkingDirectory = Environment.SystemDirectory;
/* never reached */      st = Process.Start(psi);
/* never reached */      st.WaitForExit();
```

Configure the service in windows to restart itself on failure and then do an unclean exit as @StevieB suggested.

Configure the service to restart itself with a 1000 ms delay on failure:

```
sc failure serviceName reset= 60 actions= restart/1000
```

Comment: it does not stop svc.

Comment: @dagda1: You have a deadlock.  `net` is waiting for your service to end, and you are using `st.WaitForExit()` to wait for `net` to end.

Answer (score 0):

You have a deadlock.  `net` is waiting for your service to end, and you are using `st.WaitForExit()` to wait for `net` to end.

Eventually `net` gives up waiting and closes.  Then you call `net` again.  But your service never exited in the first place, so the second `net` invocation sees the service is already started and does nothing.

Finally you return the the main service event loop and see the stop request, and your service exits.

You should be able to write a batch file with the above commands, invoke it, and return to the event loop.  Then the first `net` will wait until the service stops, and the second `net` will start it again.